# Using cursor data directly without iterating for loop

Tags: mongodb

I have a query, when I am using `find()` in my django framework it is returning a cursor `"<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000026A7CF14860>"`

when I am iterating this cursor in for loop which is returning the list of data. My problem is data which I am fetching in for loop has too much data which is affecting performance of function. So I do not want to iterate it and want to use it directly So is there any way I can call without iterating in for loop.

I checked stackoverflow

```
mask_descriptor_result = db.collection.find(query)
```

fetch data without iterating through for loop

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by it has too much data and you want to use it directly? Showing an example or your existing code would be helpful

Comment: would love to see a) existing code b) output screens c) expected output

Comment: I mean, response which I am getting have around 10,000 documents and each field in a document have very large data means hundreds of field . So when I am iterating it through loop it is affecting my performance.

Comment: When I am trying to fetch the cursor data with toArray() the it is giving error as "AttributeError: 'Cursor' object has no attribute 'toArray'"

Comment: @ishathakur because cursor isn't not array. If you are using `js` you should receive an array via of data, `.exec(callback)` at the end of your `collection.find(query)` (if you are using `mongoose` as node.js driver)
There is also no info about docs in your DB and so on.

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I am fetching with "mask_descriptor = [mask_information for mask_information in mask_descriptor_result]" ithen "mask_descriptor "is returing me list of dictionaries but I donot want to do it in this way and when I am using mask_descriptor_result.next() . It is fulfilling my condition but it is just returning first result only but I want to fetch the all the dictionary response from cursor.